# Positive sequence of integrable functions

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

The question was:

Given $\mu$ a positive measure in $(X, \Sigma)$ and $f_n, f:X\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ $\mu$-summable then show that if

$\liminf f_n\geq f$ almost everywhere and $$\limsup_n \int_X f_nd\mu \leq \int_X fd\mu$$ then  $f_n\to f$ in $ L^1$.

The hint was to prove that $g_n=\inf_{k\geq n} f_k$ satisfies $g_n\to f$ in $L^1$> I have done that via Fatou's Lemma and monotone convergence theorem, but I could not infer the main result!

Answer (score 1):

Fatou's lemma yields that
$$
\int_X \liminf_n f_n d\mu \leq \liminf _n\int_X f_n d\mu
$$
and since $f\leq \liminf_n f_n$ a.e. we have that 
$$
\int_X f d\mu \leq \liminf_n \int_X f_n d\mu
$$
and hence
$$
\limsup_n \int_X f_n d\mu \leq \int_X f d\mu \leq \liminf_n\int_X f_n d\mu.
$$
But as $\liminf_n a_n\leq \limsup a_n$ for any sequence $(a_n)$ the limit exists and we must have equality, i.e.
$$
\lim_n \int_X f_n d\mu = \limsup_n \int_X f_n d\mu = \liminf_n\int_X f_n d\mu=\int_X f d\mu.
$$

Comment: Oh, sorry I just realized that we want convergence in $L^1$ and not just convergence of the integrals. Nevermind my post for now.

Comment: Using a similar argument we have that $g_n\to f$ in L^1 but we need convergence in L^1 for $f$.